# binding files to longlistselector

Tags: xaml, binding, longlistselector

Trying to learn Win Phone 8, following along an online tutorial.  In the tutorial, the guy uses the ListBox to show files, which is working fine for me.

However, I thought we're supposed to use LongListSelector, so I added that; but nothing shows up.

If I put the LongListSelector first in the markup, neither displays when I run the app in the emulator, so I think I'm getting an exception from binding the LongListSelector.  I don't understand why though.

It's pretty simple, click a button and read files in a directory, displaying them back.

```
        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0" Grid.Row="1" >
        <Button Content="Show files" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

        <ListBox x:Name="lb">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding Path}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <phone:LongListSelector HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                x:Name="llsFiles" 
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FilesDataTemplate}"
                                />

    </StackPanel>
```

and the LLS template:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FilesDataTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

then the code-behind:

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetPackageFiles();
    }

    private async Task GetPackageFiles()
    {
        //Get the folder where the app is installed on the phone.
        var installFolder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        var imagesFolder =  await installFolder.GetFolderAsync("Images");

        var fileList = await imagesFolder.GetFilesAsync();

        lb.ItemsSource = fileList;

        llsFiles.ItemsSource = fileList.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I think I stumbled into what's going on, but don't understand it yet.  For some reason, taking off the HorizontalAlignment attribute makes the list render.  Not sure if binding happens but output is squished all the way left, or it actually makes the binding fail.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//add this declaration
List<FirstList> source = new List<FirstList>();
 public class FirstList
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string cItem { get; set; }

        public FirstList(string item)
        {
            this.cItem = item;
        }
    }
```

Then to add anything you would just do this.

```
source.Add(new FirstList(fileList.ToString());
```

make you sure you have the binding for it